# Using Microsoft Word wildcards to match timecodes

Tags: ms-word, wildcard, find-replace

I want to remove the timecodes from the Microsoft Word Document.
I have following pattern:
`00:00:00:00 - 00:00:00:00`

I am using this script:
`[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}`

But this gives me an error "Pattern Match Expression" is too complex.

If I use following script then it works fine:
`[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:`

But if I add the last two digits then it gives me an error.

For example, here my sample text:

**00:00:00:00 - 00:00:05:08
Welcome to episode 819. We're exploring enterprise AI survival with guest who is, I think I can say, genuinely an industry luminary.
00:00:19:03 - 00:00:22:20
Great to be here. Is it really? 808 19 is that many really
00:00:22:20 - 00:00:24:21
819.
00:00:24:21 - 00:00:26:14
pretty impressive. Pretty impressive.**

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a limit on the number of limiting quantifiers in the MS Word wildcard. `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` (with **7 `{2}` quantifiers**) is valid and `[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}` (with **8 `{2}` quantifiers**) throws the error you mentioned.

You can group the repetitions and apply only one limiting quantifier for the right and left parts:

```
[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3} - [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3}
```

where `(:[0-9]{2}){3}` matches `:` and two digits three times.

[image]

Comment: Hello @Wiktor, thank you for the time and help but it still gives me the same message.
If I use only first batch (before that comma) then it works fine.

Comment: @VirajShah What batch? What comma?

Comment: I mean if I use only "[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3}" then it highlights or finds the first half of that pattern. But if I use the whole formula then it gives me an error.

Comment: @VirajShah See my screenshot, it works this way.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the same but something is wrong in my doc, I think. Because now, it is searching only first pattern in the doc. There is a bunch of it in the doc but it searches or finds only one word from the doc.

Comment: @VirajShah I am not sure if you have an ASCII `-` everywhere there, try `[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3} [———-] [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3}` instead. If there can be more than one space use `[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3} @[———-] @[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3}`

Comment: This is a headache now. This formula is working but this searches only one item. But there are so many items. And there is only one comma (-).

Comment: @VirajShah `-` is a hyphen, a comma is a `,`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant hyphen. I said I am losing this one, SMH!

Comment: By the way, I am getting that result with this code:
**[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3} - [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}**

Comment: @VirajShah Use the one from my answer, I tested it and it works: `[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3} - [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){3}`

Comment: It is surprising why it is not working on my side. It gives me the result **"word found no items matching this criteria"**.

Comment: Can you share the exact text data? Copy/paste into the question to update it.

Comment: I have updated the text for your info. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @VirajShah The spaces and hyphens are ASCII so the problem you are now having is different from what you asked for in the post. I cannot help further as I do not have your data.

Comment: If I search with this **[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}** then it highlights all the data except that "space" "hyphen" and "space".
What do I need to do with those ASCII chracters? Thank you!